# Calculate the proportion of the built-up property area

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have a project, which I need to calculate the proportion of the built-up property area.
Theoretically I understand, how to calculate it, but the Problem is here:
I have 2 Layers from

> WFS: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht

One layer is Flurstueck, which tell me the Parcels from a region, where I need to calculate.
The other Layer is GebaeudeBauwerk, which tell me the built-up area from that region!
But I can't combine these Layer to calculate the proportion of the built-up property area, because they have different attribute!
I thought, that the Attributes from "oid" both Layers are the same, but they have different Values, so I can't do anything further!

After that, I need to calculate the proportion of the built-up property area as a value between 0.0 and 1.0 for each property!

This is how the Attributes look like!
[image]

Comment: they haven't any Values, which are the same, so i can't spatial join them together!

Comment: Both layers have coordinates though don't they? A spatial join is a join on coordinates, and for example, with polygons you can get a new set of polygons with all overlaps and non-overlaps of two input polygon sets.

Comment: oh, that seems right! they have both same Coordinates! can you explain more about that, i haven't join Attribute like that before!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run "[Overlap Analysis](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#overlap-analysis)" from [processing toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/de/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html). Choose *Flurstueck* as `input` and *Gebaeude* as `overlay`. The result is a duplicated Flurstueck layer with the percentage covered by buildings for each parcel as well as the area covered by them in crs units as additional attributes. *You can divide the percent result by 100 to get values between 0 and 1.*

If you only want a simple join, take a look at "[Join Attributes by Location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location)". Choose `contains` or `intersects` as predicate when using *parcels* as `base layer` and *buildings* as `join layer`. Use  `within` or `intersects` when using *buildings* as `base layer` and *parcels* as `join layer`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!